# Filter, match, calculate from date and name in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have this data

```
const data = [
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee A",
    "commission_date": "14/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 9000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee A",
    "commission_date": "17/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 5000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee B",
    "commission_date": "18/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 2000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee B",
    "commission_date": "18/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 5000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee B",
    "commission_date": "19/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 500
  }
]
```

And i want to calculate `commission_price` based on the data match `employee_name` and `commission_date`

Here, the expected output:

```
[
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee A",
    "commission_date": "14/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 9000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee A",
    "commission_date": "17/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 5000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee B",
    "commission_date": "18/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 7000
  },
  {
    "employee_name": "Employee B",
    "commission_date": "19/05/2018",
    "commission_price": 500
  }
]
```

I have tried based on answers from similar questions but the results are calculated based only from `employee_name`. here the code

```
let result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { employee_name, commission_price }) => {
  r[employee_name] = r[employee_name] || { employee_name, commission_price : 0 }
  r[employee_name].commission_price += commission_price
  return r
}, {}))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combined key for an arbitrary count of groups.

```js
var data = [{ employee_name: "Employee A", commission_date: "14/05/2018", commission_price: 9000 }, { employee_name: "Employee A", commission_date: "17/05/2018", commission_price: 5000 }, { employee_name: "Employee B", commission_date: "18/05/2018", commission_price: 2000 }, { employee_name: "Employee B", commission_date: "18/05/2018", commission_price: 5000 }, { employee_name: "Employee B", commission_date: "19/05/2018", commission_price: 500 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var key = ['employee_name', 'commission_date'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        r[key] = r[key] || { employee_name: o.employee_name, commission_date: o.commission_date, commission_price : 0 };
        r[key].commission_price += o.commission_price;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```